# os.chdir() command gives FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\ in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, file-not-found, chdir

I am using Jupyter notebook and trying to change the current working directory to my system directory i.e. 'C:/Users' but it is giving me an error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C://Users'.
However , the same is working fine in IDLE. Please help.

this is what is tried in Jupyter notebook

````
```import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(cwd)
os.chdir("C://Users")
os.getcwd()

-----------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-03f5279edef8> in <module>
      2 cwd = os.getcwd()
      3 files = os.listdir(cwd)
----> 4 os.chdir("C://Users")
      5 os.getcwd()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C://Users'
```
````

Comment: try `os.chdir(os.path.join("C:", "Users"))`

Comment: the following should work `'C:\\Users'`, `r'C:\Users'`, `'C:/Users'`.  I would not expect `'C://Users'` to work

Comment: tried 'C:\\Users', r'C:\Users', 'C:/Users' but none of these working in jupyter notebook but working in IDLE @jeschwar

Comment: since you are in a notebook have you simply tried `cd C:/Users`  ?

Comment: No.I tried os.chdir() command with all the strings inside 'C:\\Users', r'C:\Users', 'C:/Users' one by one...but failed @jeschwar